# many-to-many select: missing data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, many-to-many, relational-database

In a university db I have a many-to-many relationship between **students** and **modules** that they are registered to: using a bridging table of **status**.

The bridging table **status** has a multi-field primary key (using the unique combination of *student* and *module*; stud_id and mod_id)

However, when returning data from a general select query designed to list all this data:

```
SELECT status.stud_id, student.fname, student.sname, status.mod_id, modle.mtitle, status.grades
FROM status
INNER JOIN modle
ON status.mod_id=modle.mod_id 
INNER JOIN student
ON status.stud_id=student.stud_id 
GROUP BY status.stud_id
```

the query will not take into account that the students may have *many* modules, and will only display students as having a *single* module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you use `GROUP BY status.stud_id`? That's the reason why you have only one result for student.

I don't see any aggregate function within your query, so you probably can just delete`GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT status.stud_id, student.fname, student.sname, status.mod_id, modle.mtitle, status.grades
FROM status
INNER JOIN modle
ON status.mod_id=modle.mod_id 
INNER JOIN student
ON status.stud_id=student.stud_id
```